# Get certain rows of a treeView and fill another treeview

Tags: c#, treeview, syncfusion

How to get certain rows from TreeView with all sub rows and fill them into another treeView in c# syncfusion?

Thank you

Comment: [see](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69798/is-stack-overflow-a-code-writing-service)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I've got your point and assuming that you are copying nodes from WindowsForms TreeViews the following code may helps :

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MoveNodes(treeView1,treeView2,1, 2);
    }
    void AddRootNode(TreeView tree, TreeNode node)
    {
        var newNode = new TreeNode(node.Text);
        tree.Nodes.Add(newNode);
        foreach (TreeNode child in node.Nodes)
            AddChildNode(newNode, child);
    }
    void AddChildNode(TreeNode parent, TreeNode node)
    {
        var newNode = new TreeNode(node.Text);
        parent.Nodes.Add(newNode);
        foreach (TreeNode child in node.Nodes)
            AddChildNode(newNode, child);
    }
    private void MoveNodes(TreeView source,TreeView destination, params int[] indexes)
    {
        foreach (var index in indexes)
        {
            if (index < 0 || index >= source.Nodes.Count)
                continue;
            AddRootNode(destination, source.Nodes[index]);
        }
    }
```